# Excel reading data from table 1 and write the calculated data into table2

Tags: java

I have two tables from the same excel in a different sheets. In table 1: There are two columns like "Actual value" and "Saved Value" The cell values of two columns are looks like this Actual value : row(0)2005.99, row(1)6774.00... Saved value : row(0)ClaimsTotal, row(1)ClaimsAServiceTotal

In table 2: There is an column name called "Calculations" "Value1" "Value2" "Value3" The cell values of Calculations column looks like this Calculations: row(0)ClaimsTotal + ClaimsAServiceTotal = ClaimsGrandTotal ......etc

I have written the code for excel reading and writing, below are the methods for the reference

```
ExcelReader excelutil = new ExcelReader("Guardian Role");
Object[] savedValue = excelutil.readExcelByColName("Saved Value");
Object[] actualValue = excelutil.readExcelByColName("Actual Value");
ExcelReader readCaliTable = new ExcelReader("Data Verification");
Object[] caliculation = readCaliTable.readExcelByColName("Calculations");
```

My requirement is: First I need to split table 2 Calculations column cell value and need to keep in two different strings like value[0] = ClaimsTotal and value[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFOgo.png)=ClaimsAServiceTotal. based on this cell string I want to check this in table 1 Saved Value column, If it is present then corresponding value from table 1 Actual Value column need to get and do calculation Ex:

- `ClaimsTotal = 2005.99 (I need to print this in table 2 value 1)`
- `ClaimsAServiceTotal= 6774.00 (I need to print this in table 2 value 2)`
- `(2005.99+6774.00)= total (I need to print this in table 2 value 3) like wise in some rows there will be +,=`

```
public ExcelReader(String sheetname, String sheetname1) throws IOException {
    super();
    this.filename = configProps.getProperty("testData");;
    this.sheetname = sheetname;
    this.sheetname1 = sheetname1;
    this.excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File(this.filename));
    this.workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(this.excelFile);
    this.sheet = workbook.getSheet(this.sheetname);
    this.sheet1 = workbook.getSheet(this.sheetname1);
}

 public void verifyData(String colName) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Object[] calc = this.readExcelByColName(colName);
    for (int i = 0; i < calc.length; i++) {
        String string = (String) calc[i];
        string = string.replaceAll("\\s", "");
        String[] parts = string.split("(\\+)|(\\=)");
        int j = 1;
        for (String s : parts) {
            int[] index1 = findIndex(this.sheet1, s);
            int[] index2 = findIndex(this.sheet, string);
                this.sheet.getRow(index2[0]).getCell((index2[1] + j))
                        .setCellValue(this.sheet1.getRow(index1[0]).getCell(index1[1] - 1).getStringCellValue());
                j++;
        }
    }
    this.outFile = new FileOutputStream(new File(this.filename));
}

private int[] findIndex(Sheet sheet, String cellContent) {
    for (Row row : sheet) {
        for (Cell cell : row) {
            if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                if (cell.getStringCellValue().replaceAll("\\s", "").equals(cellContent)) {
                    int[] index = { row.getRowNum(), cell.getColumnIndex() };
                    return index;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

main method@Test

```
ExcelReader excelUtil2 = new ExcelReader("Verify Data","Guardian Angel Hospice");
    excelUtil2.verifyData("Calculations");
    Object[] data2 = excelUtil2.readExcelByColName("Value1");
    for (int i = 0; i < data2.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(data2[i]);
    }       
    excelUtil2.saveAndCloseExcel();
```

PFA Excel

[image]

Comment: *Please can some one help on coding this... I tried but could nt succeed* SO is not a coding service.  [Please add a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)